# How to group function and then filter with function in Pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I need to filter DataFrame at Pandas.

In dataframe I have columns `order_uid` and `force_number`.

First I need to group everything by `order_uid`. Then in groups filter by `force_number`.
Tricky for me is that I need to apply filtering function `zscore` which should be calculated on grouped data => it use mean and stdev.

Pseudocode for filtering is:
`df <- df %>% group_by(order_uid) %>% filter(zscore_abs(force_number)<1.5)`

Function zscore
`zscore_abs <- function(x) {abs ((x-mean(x)) / sd(x)) }`

How to apply function on filtered data?

Comment: Isn't this `r` ?

Comment: yes, it is in R but I need to write it in python